# Authentication with REST on social media website

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, authentication

If I am designing a social media website along the vein of Facebook/Twitter where users will be able to browse other peoples profiles, create public posts that appear on other users activity streams etc, and I want to design this using RESTful WCF services on the server end, with ASP MVC web on the front end, how is authentication managed? As there is no session state, every request the user makes will effectively need to be authenticated to confirm who is logged in and making each request. Eg "Search profiles", "View profile", "Update your own profile", "Upload new photo to your profile", "Post public message", "Reply to public message" are all actions the user will need to be able to do.

I assume something must need to be managed in the clients browser if the server holds no state, but how do you protect against spoofing, multiple user computers etc?

secondly, how is session lifetime managed with REST in this instance, ie if you want a user to be forced to reauthenticate out after 10 minutes of no activity, how would that be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using OAuth.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn277356.aspx

Basically once a login call is made you will have an authentication token returned that is used for all subsequent requests. All API calls will call to an authentication API to ensure the token is valid. You can expire this token at the authentication api after a set time if required.

To protect against spoofing, all calls should be made over https.

An advantage of implementing OAuth is then you can move the authentication to another provider, say google or facebook, so you do not even have to store user credentials on your site at all.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is that how so many sites these days offer the "log in via Facebook" option?